# How to check if a string is at the beginning of line in spite of tabs or whitespaces?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess as sp
args = ["awk", r'/^word/ { print $1}','anyfile.py' ]
p = sp.Popen(args, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE )
```

How to get word at the beginning of line in spite of tabs and or whitespaces?

```
print p.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a regular expression, like this

```
import re
re.match(r'^\s*word', line)
```

Here,

- `^` indicates beginning of string
- `\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters
- `word` is the actual word you are looking for.

Comment: You can also integrate that regular expression to the awk search pattern: `awk '/^\s*return/ {print $1}' test.py`. But in this case I don't see why not to open and filter the file directly in Python...

Answer (score 2):

What about using `startswith` after using `strip`-

```
>>>'\n  \t  \r  asasasas ash'.strip().startswith('asa')
>>>True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the search pattern used by awk to accept leading whitespace characters in your input file:

```
import subprocess as sp
args = ["awk", r'/^\s*word/ { print $1}','anyfile.py' ]
p = sp.Popen(args, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE )
print p.stdout.read()
```

But in this case, I don't see why not perform the parsing directly in Python:

```
with open("anyfile.py") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.lstrip().startswith("word"):
            print "found match!"
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Comment: I need to find all function names in file (args = ["awk", r'/^\s*def/ { print $2}','/home/tiko/workspace/Testing_python/qt_image_editor.py' ] ) I take second word which is after "def"

Comment: thatwhy I need to use awk

Comment: @Tigran84 Even that might not be easier using awk than Python.

Comment: @Tigran84 Also have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), because this is what I think you are trying to achieve. (Maybe in a simplified form?)

Comment: now I just learn pyqt4 and I need this option for my little program thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Using only built-in string methods it's as easy as:

`str(p.stdout.read()).split()[0]`

This should grant you the first word in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want to do is parse the abstract synatax tree of a python file using the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module. There are much better ways of doing that than using regular expressions. Here's an example:

```
import ast

class FunctionVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.second_arg_names = []

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, func):
        """collect function names and the second argument of functions that 
        have two or more arguments"""
        args = func.args.args
        if len(args) > 1:
            self.second_arg_names.append((func.name, args[1].id))
        self.generic_visit(func)

def find_func_args(filename=__file__):
    """defaults to looking at this file"""
    with open(filename) as f:
        source = f.read()
    tree = ast.parse(source)

    visitor = FunctionVisitor()
    visitor.visit(tree)

    print visitor.second_arg_names
    assert visitor.second_arg_names == [("visit_FunctionDef", "func")]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_func_args()
```